# Ubuntu 14.04 - Unknown Display, Max resolution is 1024x768

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, lenovo

I have a notebook Lenovo ThinkPad T540p with Nvidia GeForce 730M video card. Currently I have a problem to setup a correct 1920x1080 resolution on my second LG monitor, connected through VGA port.

I already tried a few solutions [1](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1364460), [2](https://superuser.com/questions/679923/ubuntus-max-resolution-is-1024x768-unknown-monitor?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but with no result (result in error on `xrandr --addmode` step).

Here is xrandr output

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2944 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080      60.1*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1600x900       60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1368x768       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   1024x576       60.0  
   960x540        60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   864x486        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
   720x405        60.0  
   640x360        60.0  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected 1024x768+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I am new to Ubuntu, any ideas will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried all possible solutions but the only one that helped me - connect monitor via HDMI cable (it was VGA initially).
My notebook has no HDMI on board, but it has `mini display port`, so I got `miniDisplayPort to HDMI` adapter and everything works great now!